# Summing across various dimensions a multi-dimensional Matlab array

Tags: matlab

Consider an `N`-D array in Matlab composed of `(nbins)^(N-2)` sub-matrices of size `nbins x nbins`.

For example,

```
clear
rng default
N=5;
nbins=3;
A=randn(nbins,nbins,nbins,nbins,nbins);
```

Let `M` be an integer less or equal than `N`. I want to write a generic code that gives me an `M`-D array, `B`, obtained by summing `A` along the dimensions `M+1,M+2,...,N`.

For example, continuing above,

```
M=4;
%B is nbins x nbins x nbins x nbins with 
B=A(:,:,:,:,1)+A(:,:,:,:,2)+A(:,:,:,:,3); 

M=3;
%B is nbins x nbins x nbins with 
B_temp=A(:,:,:,:,1)+A(:,:,:,:,2)+A(:,:,:,:,3);
B=B_temp(:,:,:,1)+B_temp(:,:,:,2)+B_temp(:,:,:,3);

M=2
%B is nbins x nbins  with 
B_temp1=A(:,:,:,:,1)+A(:,:,:,:,2)+A(:,:,:,:,3);
B_temp2=B_temp(:,:,:,1)+B_temp(:,:,:,2)+B_temp(:,:,:,3);
B= B_temp2(:,:,1)+B_temp2(:,:,2)+B_temp2(:,:,3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Since R2018b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2018b&endrelease=R2018b&category=data-analysis), the function [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html#mw_a0641061-edb0-4956-a9bd-949c6057ec15) can sum along multiple dimensions simultaneously. Thus, you can sum over the dimensions `M+1` through `N` by

```matlab
B = sum(A,M+1:N);
```

---

For older versions of MATLAB, you could sum over each dimension in turn:

```matlab
B = A
for ii=M+1:N
   B = sum(B,ii);
end
```

However, [Luis’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57469213/7328782) will be more performant in the pre-R2018b case because it avoids the intermediate storage, and does just one pass over the array (at least if all dimensions to be summed over are contiguous, for non-contiguous dimensions you should time these two approaches to see which is faster).

Comment: I know it's not in the question, but I'm wondering how to adjust your code if instead I want to get  an `(N-M)`-D array, `B`, obtained by summing `A` along the dimensions `1,...,M`. I have the feeling it is straightforward from your answer and I don't think it is worth a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: I think one option could be : `B = A; for ii=1:M jj=M-ii+1; B = sum(B,jj); B=squeeze(B); end`

Comment: @user3285148: loop `ii=1:M`, and don’t change anything about the loop contents.  Then put the `squeeze` after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sum along several *contiguous* dimensions, it's very easy to collapse those dimensions into one using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), and then sum over that dimension. This approach applies [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) over one dimension only, and thus works even in versions before R2018b, which don't support summing over multiple dimensions at once.

```
sz = size(A);
B = sum(reshape(A, [sz(1:M) prod(sz(M+1:end))]), M+1);
```

(If the dimensions to sum over were not contiguous, [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) would be needed before `reshape` to make them contiguous, and the code might be slightly slower.)

Comment: That’s a very clean and simple solution. Nice!